# Ruby: Merging variables in to a string

Tags: ruby, string

I'm looking for a better way to merge variables into a string, in Ruby.

For example if the string is something like:

"The `animal` `action` the `second_animal`"

And I have variables for `animal`, `action` and `second_animal`, what is the prefered way to put those variables in to the string?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to write something like this:

```
"The #{animal} #{action} the #{second_animal}"
```

Note the double quotes (") surrounding the string: this is the trigger for Ruby to use its built-in placeholder substitution. You cannot replace them with single quotes (') or the string will be kept as is.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I simplified the problem too much. The String will be pulled from a database, and the variable dependant  a number of factors. 

Normally I would use a replace for 1 or two varibles, but this has the potential to be more. Any thoughts?

Comment: The #{} construct is probably the fastest (although that still seems counterintuitive to me). As well as gix's suggestion, you can also assemble strings with + or <<, but there may be some intermediate strings created, which is costly.

Comment: Best way to interpolate variables

Comment: what does *idiomatic* means?

Comment: "idiomatic": following the conventions of the language, writing code using the features of the language, rather than trying to force it into looking like another language.

Answer (score 128):

You can use sprintf-like formatting to inject values into the string. For that the string must include placeholders. Put your arguments into an array and use on of these ways:
(For more info look at [the documentation for Kernel::sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005984).)

```
fmt = 'The %s %s the %s'
res = fmt % [animal, action, other_animal]  # using %-operator
res = sprintf(fmt, animal, action, other_animal)  # call Kernel.sprintf
```

You can even explicitly specify the argument number and shuffle them around:

```
'The %3$s %2$s the %1$s' % ['cat', 'eats', 'mouse']
```

Or specify the argument using hash keys:

```
'The %{animal} %{action} the %{second_animal}' %
  { :animal => 'cat', :action=> 'eats', :second_animal => 'mouse'}
```

Note that you must provide a value for all arguments to the `%` operator. For instance, you cannot avoid defining `animal`.

Answer (score 20):

I would use the `#{}` constructor, as stated by the other answers.
I also want to point out there is a real subtlety here to watch out for here:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > first_name = 'jim'
 => "jim" 
2.0.0p247 :002 > second_name = 'bob'
 => "bob" 
2.0.0p247 :003 > full_name = '#{first_name} #{second_name}'
 => "\#{first_name} \#{second_name}" # not what we expected, expected "jim bob"
2.0.0p247 :004 > full_name = "#{first_name} #{second_name}"
 => "jim bob" #correct, what we expected
```

While strings can be created with single quotes (as demonstrated by the `first_name` and `last_name` variables, **the `#{}` constructor can only be used in strings with double quotes.**

Answer (score 15):

```
["The", animal, action, "the", second_animal].join(" ")
```

is another way to do it.

Answer (score 11):

This is called string interpolation, and you do it like this:

```
"The #{animal} #{action} the #{second_animal}"
```

Important: it will only work when string is inside double quotes (" ").

Example of code that will not work as you expect:

```
'The #{animal} #{action} the #{second_animal}'
```

Comment: Thank you for using the proper term so new programmers can learn: interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

The standard ERB templating system may work for your scenario.

```
def merge_into_string(animal, second_animal, action)
  template = 'The <%=animal%> <%=action%> the <%=second_animal%>'
  ERB.new(template).result(binding)
end

merge_into_string('tiger', 'deer', 'eats')
=> "The tiger eats the deer"

merge_into_string('bird', 'worm', 'finds')
=> "The bird finds the worm"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with your local variables, like this:

`@animal = "Dog"`

`@action = "licks"`

`@second_animal = "Bird"`

`"The #{@animal} #{@action} the #{@second_animal}"`

the output would be: "The **Dog** **licks** the **Bird**"