# replace variable with its value in a ruby string, string itself is stored in a variable?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a variable containing a string and in run time i was to replace some variables which are stored in that string.

for example..

```
 my_string = "Congrats you have joined groupName."
 groupName = "*Name of my group*"
  puts my_string
```

Output:-

```
 "Congrats you have joined *name of the group*"
```

issue is:

```
my_string = " Congrats you have joined #{groupName}" expects groupName already exists.. but in my case i have to define my_string before variable in it.
```

Solution 1:

One way can be.. string replacment like using gsub.. but thats not good one..

PS:

What I am trying to achieve. We have some set of 100 messages that we have to deliver. I want to define at one single place and just replace some variable when needed. Now i want to define all these variables(100 ones) in the application_controller, so that I can just concatenate each variable(one of 100) defined. And automatically variable(variable which is defined in the string stored in one of those 100 variables).
 *This language is quite confusing.. Check the example i explained above..*

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554666/ruby-merging-variables-in-to-a-string

Comment: `my_string = " Congrats you have joined #{groupName}" expects groupName already exists.. but in my case i have to define my_string before variable in it.` isn't valid Ruby code. It also isn't valid English.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could store a format string:

```
my_string = "Congrats you have joined %s"
group_name = "My Group"
puts my_string % group_name # prints: Congrats you have joined My Group
```

For multiple variables in the same string you can use

```
my_string = "Congrats you have joined %s %s"
group_name = ['group1', 'group2']
puts my_string % ['group1', 'group2']
```

will result:--

```
"Congrats you have joined group1 group2"
```

Comment: my_string % ['group1', 'group2']

Answer (score 30):

Or you can do this:

```
2.0.0-p247 :034 > a = "I love my live, says %{who}"
 => "I love my live, says %{who}" 
2.0.0-p247 :035 > a % { :who => "me" }
 => "I love my live, says me"
```

Comment: This is why Ruby is so cool. If anyone is curious, this is documented in the [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) documentation (last example).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation) functionality to replace variables:

```
I18n.backend.store_translations :en, 
  :congrats => 'Congrats you have joined %{group_name}!'
I18n.translate :congrats, :group_name => 'My Group'
# => 'Congrats you have joined My Group!'
```

This way you only have a single point to maintain your texts. Your `application_controller` is not the best place for static texts.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_string = "Congrats you have joined groupName."
groupName = "*Name of my group*"
puts my_string.gsub('groupName',groupName)
```

Output :

```
"Congrats you have joined *name of the group*"
```

What it does is search for the 'groupName' string and replace it with the content of the groupName variable

Comment: It's only a gsub not a gsub! it doesn't modify the object but create a new string

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval to replace variables in runtime :

```
my_string = 'Congrats you have joined #{groupName}.'
groupName = "*Name of my group*"
puts eval('"'+ my_string +'"')
```

Comment: check my question. I specified whats the issue with this format.

Comment: Mohit, pay attention to single quotes in my_string "'", this expression won't be evaluated until you use eval, so you can define string before defining variable..