# Ruby: Variable inside a variable

Tags: ruby

I am just starting in Ruby, I am facing the following issue.

```
ip_array = [1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2]

for i in 0..1
    puts `ping #{ip_array[#{i}]}`

end
```

This gives me an error: unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ']'

however this works

```
ip_array = [1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2]

for i in 0..1
    puts `ping #{ip_array[i]}`

end
```

Can someone explain this, I think think `#{ip_array[#{i}]}` is more correct than `#{ip_array[i]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the version `#{ip_array[i]}` is the correct one because variables are substituted inside ruby strings using the syntax: `#{<var_name>}`, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554666/ruby-merging-variables-in-to-a-string).

So you cannot use a hashtag ('#') inside a variable name, like you are trying in `#{ip_array[#{i}]` since this marks the beginning of a new variable subsitution and the previous substitution is not finished yet.

`#ip_array[i]` is only one variable substituted in the string not two variables.