# I need some assistance defining variables in a chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Here is the LDAP command that I want to run, which works perfectly:

```
/opt/openldap/setup —cli —no-prompt —rootUserDN "cn=Directory Manager" — rootUserPasswpord secretpass —hostname localhost —ldapPort 389 —adminConnectorPort 4444 —baseDN "dc=example,dc=com" —addBaseEntry —doNotStart —acceptLicense'
```

Here is the content of my chef attribute file (`server.rb`)

```
default["openldap"]["server"]["ROOTDN"] = "cn=Directory Manager"
default["openldap"]["server"]["ROOTPASS"] = "secret pass"
default["openldap"]["server"]["LDAPPORT"] = "389"
default["openldap"]["server"]["ADMINPORT"] = "4444"
default["openldap"]["server"]["BASEDN"] = "dc=example,dc=com"
default["openldap"]["server"]["DJDEST"] = "/opt/openldap"
```

Here is the content of my chef recipe file (default.rb)

```
execute 'Ldap: Installing Openldap Instance' do
  command node["openldap"]["server"]["DJDEST"]'/setup --cli --no-prompt--rootUserDN "["openldap"]["server"]["ROOTDN"] " --rootUserPassword ["openldap"]  ["server"]["ROOTPASS"]--hostname ["openldap"]["server"]["ODJFQDN"] --ldapPort ["openldap"]["server"]["LDAPPORT"] --adminConnectorPort ["openldap"]["server"]["ADMINPORT"] --baseDN "["openldap"]["server"]["BASEDN"]" --addBaseEntry --doNotStart --acceptLicense'
  action :run
end
```

I want to run the execute resource using variables instead of manually hardcoding the ldap script in the code block. Can anyone please advice me on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hey. Welcome to StackOverflow. I tried a bit to improve the syntax, but you seem to have couple of issues. What quotes are you using? Could you please double-check all the things you pasted and I tried to fix so that we get your real problem?

Comment: Is your problem actually string interpolation in ruby, so that you want to combine an attribute and a string together? like `node[...] + '/setup ..' `?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand your question right, you want to generate a string from few variables and strings. Then your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554666/ruby-merging-variables-in-to-a-string).

You could either combine the content of a variable `a = "foo"` and the string `"bar"` using:

```rb
a = "foo"
b = a + "bar"
```

Or you can use string interpolation (probably more common):

```rb
a = "foo"
b = "#{a}bar"
```

The result in both cases is `"foobar"`.

Translated to your chef context, the resulting execute resource would be:

```rb
execute 'Ldap: Installing Openldap Instance' do
  command "#{node['openldap']['server']['DJDEST']}/setup --cli --no-prompt--rootUserDN "#{node['openldap']['server']['ROOTDN']}" --rootUserPassword #{node['openldap']['server']['ROOTPASS']} --hostname #{node['openldap']['server']['ODJFQDN']} --ldapPort #{node['openldap']['server']['LDAPPORT']} --adminConnectorPort #{node['openldap']['server']['ADMINPORT']} --baseDN "#{node['openldap']['server']['BASEDN']}" --addBaseEntry --doNotStart --acceptLicense"
  action :run
end
```

If it makes it easier for you, you can also extract this into a variable:

```rb
installLdapCommand = "#{node['openldap']['server']['DJDEST']}/setup --cli --no-prompt--rootUserDN #{node['openldap']['server']['ROOTDN']} --rootUserPassword #{node['openldap']['server']['ROOTPASS']} --hostname #{node['openldap']['server']['ODJFQDN']} --ldapPort #{node['openldap']['server']['LDAPPORT']} --adminConnectorPort #{node['openldap']['server']['ADMINPORT']} --baseDN "#{node['openldap']['server']['BASEDN']}" --addBaseEntry --doNotStart --acceptLicense"
execute 'Ldap: Installing Openldap Instance' do
  command installLdapCommand
  action :run
end
```

Comment: Thanks StephenKing. Justmiles solution below worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
'["openldap"]["server"]["ROOTDN"] --option'
```

try using ruby's string interpolation

```
"#{node['openldap']['server"]['ROOTDN']} --option"
```

Like so:

```
execute 'Ldap: Installing Openldap Instance' do
  command "#{node['openldap']['server']['DJDEST']}/setup --cli --no-prompt--rootUserDN #{node['openldap']['server']['ROOTDN']} --rootUserPassword #{node['openldap']['server']['ROOTPASS']} --hostname #{node['openldap']['server']['ODJFQDN']} --ldapPort #{node['openldap']['server']['LDAPPORT']} --adminConnectorPort #{node['openldap']['server']['ADMINPORT']} --baseDN #{node['openldap']['server']['BASEDN']} --addBaseEntry --doNotStart --acceptLicense"
  action :run
end
```

Comment: Thank you justMiles. You suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem @jebjeb. Be sure to mark an answer as "accepted" if it resolved your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer