# how do i combine variables?

Tags: ruby, variables

im making a program and i need to combine a lot of variables, most of them strings but i have some int, by doing this

```
name = "#{variable1}#{variable2}"
name2 = "#{variable2}#{variable1}"
```

it´s a simple example with just two variables but thats the idea, what im trying to make. i am doing all the possibilities one by one, even when is more than two variables but there are many combinations. Is there an easy way to do it or i have to do it one by one?Also, do i need to write the quotation marks separately or that way is fine?

Comment: please provide example input and desired output. "i am doing all the possibilities one by one" is unclear.

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554666/ruby-merging-variables-in-to-a-string

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
variable1 = "cat"
variable2 = 9
variable3 = "lives"
arr = [variable1, variable2, variable3]
  #=> ["cat", 9, "lives"] 
arr.join    
  #=> "cat9lives"
```

Comment: Or simply `arr.join`

Comment: @Stefan, at times you (more than anyone else) make me feel really stupid. :-) Fixed. (Readers: I previously had `arr.each_with_object('') { |obj, str| str << "#{obj}" }`).

Answer (score 0):

Put all or some of these variables into an array which will produce the combinations easier.

```
s1 = 'a'
s2 = 'b'
s3 = 'c'
 n = 8
[s1, s2, s3, n].combination(3).map(&:join)
=> ["abc", "ab8", "ac8", "bc8"]
```

Above example assumes that you will pick any of 3 variables from the array and calculate the combinations. You may want to adjust that number to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of programming is not doing all possibilities one by one. "there are many combinations": they look like permutations to me. If that is the case:

```
var1 = "aa"
var2 = "bb"
var3 = 2

res = [var1, var2, var3].permutation.map{|perm| perm.join}
p res #=> ["aabb2", "aa2bb", "bbaa2", "bb2aa", "2aabb", "2bbaa"]
```